# How to I force a get request in a rails route with IE9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, post, routes

I dont get it but for some reason when i visit the site that i am working on and visiting this url in ie9 i get this error

```
Started GET "/wheels/5/change" for 208.104.677.174 at 2011-12-25 18:56:02 -0500

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action '55' could not be found for WheelsController):
```

all other browsers seem to work fine but IE9

here is my route for this

```
resources :wheels do
  member do
    post :default
    post :change
  end
end
```

but as you can see in IE its being sent as a get request....any ideas

Here is the link

```
<%= link_to 'Set', default_wheel_path(wheel), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :post %>
```

Comment: What are you doing? Is it a link? Is it a form tag? How is IE being told to make this request?

Comment: its a link...let me give you the link one sec

Comment: <%= link_to 'Set', default_wheel_path(wheel), :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :post %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links in Rails 3 now require JavaScript to be enabled and the jquery-ujs lib. Make sure you are including jquery and jquery-ujs in your layout.

Comment: check the browser error log and the html output, something is probably missing in there.

Comment: also, firefox and chrome implement html5 links correctly so this could be the issue with IE.

Comment: <a href="/wheels/5/change" rel="nofollow" data-method="post">

Comment: also it looks like prototype and jquery is included as well as a jQuery no conflict

Comment: Please add it to the question, also, add the full HTML for your page (or at least everything inside the <head> tag).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6129/discussion-between-tamer-and-mauricio-linhares)